# Craft CMS 3 data structure advice for vehicle make, model, trim, year tagging

Tags: craft3, fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype, table-field, plugin-supertable

Hi i really would like some advise on best practices on setting up some data for my Craft APP.

Most of my documents will be linked to vehicle make/model/trim/year. EG Audi A5 Sport 2009-2016 and/Or Audi A5 Sportback 2017+ .

What would be the best way to do this? Would it be to create a new field type or use something like a table?

**My First Idea was to do the following:**

*A Structure*

- Level 1 : Vehicle Make

  - Level 2 : Vehicle Model

    - Level 3 : Vehicle Trim

Then create a field (table) where i select either the trim or model, then select a date range.

But what i want to do is in the front end select documents by everything under Make and/or Model and/or Trim and/or Year

But i am not sure this is the best solution.

Can anyone recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Goal**: Filter documents by related vehicle characteristics.

My first idea would be to create it as such:

- Create an assets volume where all your documents will be uploaded to.
- Create a vehicle category group for your vehicles such as you already defined (the structure you mentioned)
- Add 2 fields to the assets volume:

  - Vehicle (category field)
  - Year (date field)

This will allow you to add the relevant data to each document. You can than [display](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/asset-queries.html) the documents on your frontend and search/filter them by category and/or date. 
How you do that is up to you, either with Twig serverside or with VueJS for example client side.